# Autocomplete while writing text inside edittext - usage of external script in Kotlin

Tags: javascript, kotlin, android-edittext, embed

I want to make autocompletion while user is filling the edittext, there is a nice github js for this, therefore I want to integrate it. The github link is as follows:

https://github.com/konsalex/Airport-Autocomplete-JS

And the script inside it for installation is this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/airport-autocomplete-js@latest/dist/index.browser.min.js"></script>
```

I couldn't find any resource for this in stackoverflow, even for installation and for usage. Is there a way for that?

Comment: I don't know what your options are for running JavaScript inside Android (besides using a ``WebView``) but if nobody has any suggestions, you probably want to use the ``AutoCompleteTextView`` widget: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: @cactustictacs Thank you for your reply. Yes these days forum is at rest I think. As I mentioned, there is a javascript code, is there an implementation example of js code inside autocompletetextview? Or maybe any other ways if exist?

Comment: This github project is exactly what I want but I don't know how to apply it

Comment: JavaScript is a completely different language and framework unfortunately, that library is designed for web apps. The only way I know to run js is either with a ``WebView``, or a library like Square's https://github.com/cashapp/quickjs-java - either way, if you want it to communicate with native components like an ``EditText``, you've got a bit of work on your hands. It's not going to be a simple drop-in like sticking it in a web page. Honestly if I were you I'd learn how to make ``AutoCompleteTextView`` work, and learn how to parse the JSON from the airport library to get the adapter data

Comment: @cactustictacs Thank you, I didn't know applying js to kotlin is such complicated, your suggestion is good then, I need to parse the data and set it to adapter programmatically, it is bad that such a useful github project cannot be used in mobile programming and just for web:(